# is it necessary to use signInWIthPopup to authenticate with google using firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

Is it necessary to use either `firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)` or `firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);` ?

Can we directly authenticate google credentials from the login page of our angular app?

Correct me if i'm wrong.

What I exactly need is after we enter credentials in our login page, by clicking login, can we authenticate google creds without having to enter our google creds in a pop-up page or redirected page to google.

Answer (score 0):

You can't ask user for their Google credentials on the page. It would be a huge security risk. Imagine if any app can do so, it would equivalent of a phishing attack and a user's entire google account would be compromised. OAuth flows are designed to mitigate that and OAuth works through a redirect flow. The user never enters their credentials in a 3rd party site and the OAuth tokens granted have a short lifetime, are revocable and limited to authorize only specific scopes which a user clearly consents/declines to ahead of time.